# Unable to install programs

Tags: command-line, upgrade, software-installation, sudo, 17.04

So I don't know how this happened, but every time I try to install something or do an update, it won't finish and fails. I am using Ubuntu 17.04. Here's what happens when I try to run `sudo apt upgrade`:

```
into@poppistus:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.10.0-24 linux-headers-4.10.0-24-generic
  linux-image-4.10.0-24-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-24-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apport click firefox firefox-locale-en firefox-locale-fi gir1.2-click-0.4
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome-calendar
  gnome-desktop3-data gnome-settings-daemon-schemas imagemagick
  imagemagick-6-common imagemagick-6.q16 irssi libc-bin libclick-0.4-0
  libgnome-desktop-3-12 libgnutls30 libimage-magick-perl
  libimage-magick-q16-perl libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libldap-2.4-2
  libldap-common libmagick++-6.q16-7 libmagickcore-6.q16-3
  libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-3 libmirclient9
  libmircommon7 libmircookie2 libmircore1 libmirplatform15 libmirprotobuf3
  libmirserver43 libmwaw-0.3-3 libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnm-glib-vpn1
  libnm-glib4 libnm-util2 libnm0 libsndfile1 libssl1.0.0 libtasn1-6
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 lintian linux-generic
  linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic locales mir-client-platform-mesa5
  mir-graphics-drivers-desktop mir-platform-graphics-mesa-kms12
  mir-platform-graphics-mesa-x12 mir-platform-input-evdev6 multiarch-support
  network-manager openssl python3-click-package python3-distupgrade sudo
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
65 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/151 MB of archives.
After this operation, 310 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 263567 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apport_2.20.4-0ubuntu4.1_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.prerm: 19: /var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.prerm: pyclean: Permission denied
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 126
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 19: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: pyclean: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.20.4-0ubuntu4.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 126
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.postinst: 13: /var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.postinst: pycompile: Permission denied
*** Error in `/usr/bin/dpkg': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000564558183bf8 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7908b)[0x7f74655da08b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x1f8)[0x7f74655e7ed8]
/usr/bin/dpkg(+0x20cd0)[0x564555e87cd0]
/usr/bin/dpkg(+0x21119)[0x564555e88119]
/usr/bin/dpkg(+0x283cd)[0x564555e8f3cd]
/usr/bin/dpkg(+0x17737)[0x564555e7e737]
/usr/bin/dpkg(+0x17915)[0x564555e7e915]
/usr/bin/dpkg(+0x17b5d)[0x564555e7eb5d]
/usr/bin/dpkg(+0xaed7)[0x564555e71ed7]
/usr/bin/dpkg(+0x20c0b)[0x564555e87c0b]
/usr/bin/dpkg(+0x20e01)[0x564555e87e01]
/usr/bin/dpkg(+0xa962)[0x564555e71962]
/usr/bin/dpkg(+0x72fd)[0x564555e6e2fd]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7f74655813f1]
/usr/bin/dpkg(+0x743a)[0x564555e6e43a]
======= Memory map: ========
564555e67000-564555eac000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 11796786                   /usr/bin/dpkg
5645560ac000-5645560af000 r--p 00045000 fd:00 11796786                   /usr/bin/dpkg
5645560af000-5645560b0000 rw-p 00048000 fd:00 11796786                   /usr/bin/dpkg
5645560b0000-5645562c4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
564557bc4000-56455afd2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7f7464069000-7f746407f000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 25690128                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f746407f000-7f746427e000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 25690128                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f746427e000-7f746427f000 r--p 00015000 fd:00 25690128                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f746427f000-7f7464280000 rw-p 00016000 fd:00 25690128                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f7464280000-7f746428b000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 25690165                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.24.so
7f746428b000-7f746448a000 ---p 0000b000 fd:00 25690165                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.24.so
7f746448a000-7f746448b000 r--p 0000a000 fd:00 25690165                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.24.so
7f746448b000-7f746448c000 rw-p 0000b000 fd:00 25690165                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.24.so
7f746448c000-7f7464492000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7464492000-7f746449d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 25690167                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.24.so
7f746449d000-7f746469c000 ---p 0000b000 fd:00 25690167                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.24.so
7f746469c000-7f746469d000 r--p 0000a000 fd:00 25690167                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.24.so
7f746469d000-7f746469e000 rw-p 0000b000 fd:00 25690167                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.24.so
7f746469e000-7f74646b4000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 25690159                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.24.so
7f74646b4000-7f74648b3000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 25690159                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.24.so
7f74648b3000-7f74648b4000 r--p 00015000 fd:00 25690159                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.24.so
7f74648b4000-7f74648b5000 rw-p 00016000 fd:00 25690159                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.24.so
7f74648b5000-7f74648b7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f74648b7000-7f74648bf000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 25690160                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.24.so
7f74648bf000-7f7464abe000 ---p 00008000 fd:00 25690160                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.24.so
7f7464abe000-7f7464abf000 r--p 00007000 fd:00 25690160                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.24.so
7f7464abf000-7f7464ac0000 rw-p 00008000 fd:00 25690160                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.24.so
7f7464ac0000-7f7464ecc000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 11797986                   /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f7464ecc000-7f7464ee4000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 25690314                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.24.so
7f7464ee4000-7f74650e4000 ---p 00018000 fd:00 25690314                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.24.so
7f74650e4000-7f74650e5000 r--p 00018000 fd:00 25690314                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.24.so
7f74650e5000-7f74650e6000 rw-p 00019000 fd:00 25690314                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.24.so
7f74650e6000-7f74650ea000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f74650ea000-7f74650ed000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 25690155                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so
7f74650ed000-7f74652ec000 ---p 00003000 fd:00 25690155                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so
7f74652ec000-7f74652ed000 r--p 00002000 fd:00 25690155                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so
7f74652ed000-7f74652ee000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 25690155                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so
7f74652ee000-7f7465360000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 25690207                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.3
7f7465360000-7f746555f000 ---p 00072000 fd:00 25690207                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.3
7f746555f000-7f7465560000 r--p 00071000 fd:00 25690207                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.3
7f7465560000-7f7465561000 rw-p 00072000 fd:00 25690207                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.3
7f7465561000-7f746571f000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 25690151                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
7f746571f000-7f746591e000 ---p 001be000 fd:00 25690151                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
7f746591e000-7f7465922000 r--p 001bd000 fd:00 25690151                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
7f7465922000-7f7465924000 rw-p 001c1000 fd:00 25690151                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
7f7465924000-7f7465928000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7465928000-7f746594d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 25690210                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f746594d000-7f7465b4c000 ---p 00025000 fd:00 25690210                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f7465b4c000-7f7465b4d000 r--p 00024000 fd:00 25690210                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f7465b4d000-7f7465b4e000 rw-p 00025000 fd:00 25690210                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f7465b4e000-7f7465b50000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7465b50000-7f7465b76000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 25690116                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
7f7465d4d000-7f7465d4f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7465d71000-7f7465d75000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7465d75000-7f7465d76000 r--p 00025000 fd:00 25690116                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
7f7465d76000-7f7465d77000 rw-p 00026000 fd:00 25690116                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
7f7465d77000-7f7465d78000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffeb6364000-7ffeb6385000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffeb63cd000-7ffeb63cf000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffeb63cf000-7ffeb63d1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg exited unexpectedly
```

I would really like to get this fixed and I will be very thankful for even the littlest help!

Comment: Take a look at this, it seems to be the same problem and has an accepted answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48402/dpkg-new-pre-installation-script-returned-error-exit-status-1

Comment: @OrganicMarble I don't think that's the relevant answer. Just before the backtrace you can see that pycompile and others say Permission denied.

Comment: @IntoAlmiala try running `apt-get upgrade` as root user without sudo

Comment: I'm more worried about `Error in '/usr/bin/dpkg': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer`

Comment: @Zanna Oh yeah - https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=824542, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1604821

Comment: Didn't find an answer from those links. Also running the command as root didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by doing the next set of commands:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.* /tmp/
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq apport
sudo apt remove apport
sudo apt autoremove && sudo appt autoclean
```

Thanks for the help everyone!